# Tapestry5 : No service implements the interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext

Tags: spring, tapestry

I'm using the Tapestry5 [**tapx** template library](http://tapestry.formos.com/projects/tapx/tapx-templating/) to send an html email, as per [this example](https://github.com/hlship/tapx/blob/master/tapx-templating/src/test/java/com/howardlewisship/tapx/templating/integration/SendMail.java).

When I run the example I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No service implements the interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.getService(RegistryImpl.java:560)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ObjectLocatorImpl.getService(ObjectLocatorImpl.java:44)
```

All the tapestry-* jars, including tapestry-spring-5.1.05.jar are in my classpath.

Any clues as to what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you also have Spring on the classpath?

Comment: are you using an IDE that can debug the program? if so, breakpoint the constructor of this class: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tapestry/tapestry5/trunk/tapestry-spring/src/main/java/org/apache/tapestry5/spring/SpringModule.java to confirm that spring is initialising. if it isn't it's likely that it isn't actually on the classpath.

Comment: Confirmed. Breakpoint hit. I'm not sure that's the problem anyway - I'm also not sure why Tapestry is loading the SpringModule.

Comment: the SpringModule is supposed to be run by tapestry. is that the whole stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. SpringIOC loads all modules it find on the classpath. The SpringModule, in tapestry-spring.jar, attempts to initialise the ApplicactionContext service, which causes the problem.

Removing tapestry-spring.jar from the classpath fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the directions on the web site carefully; my guess is that you are not using the special TapestrySpringFilter (instead of the normal TapestryFilter).

It's been a while since I looked at this code; I can't remember if the ApplicationContext is exposed as a service or injectable object.  Seems like it should be.

Comment: Hi Howard. Isn't the use of the TapestrySpringFilter for web apps? I'm using the tapx templating library - to send html emails, didn't think I had a need for Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Fair enough; not sure what you situation is, but you should look in more detail at what TapestrySpringFilter does in terms of set up and replicate it into your standalone app's startup. There's some special bootstrapping magic that you will want to leverage.

Comment: OK will defn do, thanks! (does this still apply if I'm not using Spring, or T5 web, but just a standalone application?)